# Rename and saving remote image to server

Tags: php, php-5.3

i'm looking for a simple way to download remote images to my sever, rename and save image name to database.

I know how to download the file easily to my sever

```
copy('http://example.com/file.jpeg', '/tmp/file.jpeg');
```

But how to i rename the image while downloading or after download?

I would really appropriate if anyone can tell me a simple way to do this using php

Comment: This is a joke right?

Answer (score 2):

In `copy` function just change file name:

```
copy('http://example.com/file.jpeg', '/tmp/any_file_name.jpeg');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the Job

```
rename("/tmp/tmp_file.jpg", "/home/user/login/docs/my_file.jpg");
```

you have to do this after you downloaded it

or just change the file name while you dwonload it e.g.

```
copy('http://example.com/file.jpeg', '/tmp/some_name.jpg');
```